# When page load how to maintain the textbox value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have four textbox and two dropdown.These should placed into in Panel.This page get refresh every one minute.If i enter data into textbox,After one minute that textbox values refreshed.So how to maintain the textbox values when page refresh or load.It is possible to jquery.But I dont know jquery much.So please help me.I am using Asp.net,Jquery,C#.

Comment: If these are server-side text inputs, you can probably store the values in a variable on refresh, do a `Is PostBack` check, and reload the variables.

Comment: have your tried the option of `Updatepanel`?

Comment: Yes,server side means its easy..but i am using panel.so if panel refresh wants to maintain textbox values.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot persist variable value using javacript/Jquery.
Those collection of object will flush during each page load.One way is that you have to implement One **asp Hidden field or view state** in you page and store the value in those control and repopulate using javacript/Jquery

sample code:

Aspx code;

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdTextValues" />
```

Add value from cs code try to do in page load it self.
cod:

```
hdTextValues.Value = "TxtValue1,TxtValue2,TxtValue3,TxtValue4";
```

JavaScript function you have to call in ready method.
Code:

```
function FillText() {
    var text =$("#hdTextValues").val().split(',');
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        $("#TextBoxId" + i).val(text[i]);
    }
}
```

function call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
FillText();
});
```

Happy coding.Let me know if you have any issues

Comment: Thank you.if textbox place in panel or update panel.but when page load textbox values not refresh.

Comment: That is also pretty good option. all is based on you you can decide.If answer solve your problem or your question only you have to check as answer

Answer (score 0):

> Approach One

`<asp:UpdatePanel>` with `UpdateMode ="Conditional"` is better option when you are sure that your txt values are not going to change after postback.

> Point to Check

IF you are not resetting values in PageLoad

> Other Approch

Bind your textbox everytime on `Page_Load` like

```
Protected Void Page_Load(object Sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (IsPostBack)
  {
    TextBox1.Text = Request["TextBox1"].ToString();
  }
}
```