# Textbox values cleared while refresh in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

While i click browser refresh button(I Locked F5 and Ctrl+R) entered values in textbox cleared.Values not saved in asp viewstate so its cleared.How can i maintain entered textbox values while browser refresh?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I mainain the state of checkbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12146509/how-do-i-mainain-the-state-of-checkbox)

Comment: No.Thats different.While binding values to grid view it will reset.

Comment: You'd need some sort of autosave model to do that. ie on leaving the page without hitting ok or cancel save the partially entered data somewhere. Then you see if you have a partially saved version and use that to pre-populate the form. Save or Cancel should remove the 'draft' entry.

Comment: @Tony Hi .Somewhere means in page UI page itself ?If i saved in Hidden or somewhere means that also cleared on pages refresh And i have more fields so cant save and again assign.Is there any otherway?

Answer (score 0):

you  can either keep the value in cookie or session so that you can set those value from session or cookie

Comment: I want to maintain entered values in textbox.I think its not possible in session,Because it will clear while click refresh button.How to stop page refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the value in session or hidden field and session will not clear on page refresh.

Comment: Hi,I entered values in textbox.after that click refresh button in browser.so here we cant create session(before going to codebehind) and i have more textbox fields so its not possible i think..

Comment: you can create a function which gets the value from textbox and store in hidden field and call that function onblur of textbox. i can give you sample code if you want.

Comment: similar approch http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17449195/when-page-load-how-to-maintain-the-textbox-value